# How do I show attributes for has_many associations in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many

I have a Contact which has_many Campaigns.

And a Campaign has_many Contacts.

However, a Contact may have a start_date and a status for each Campaign.

For Example:

```
 Contact A   is active and start_date = 4/4/11 for Campaign 1 

 Contact A   is stopped and start_date = 3/2/11 for Campaign 1
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`has_many :through` lets you define attributes on the join table which pertain to the relationship itself.

```
class Contact
  has_many :campaign_contacts
  has_many :campaigns, :through => :campaign_contacts
end

class CampaignContact
  belongs_to :contact
  belongs_to :campaign
end

class Campaign
  has_many :campaign_contacts
  has_many :contacts, :through => :campaign_contacts
end
```

Normally you would just add the foreign keys to the join table and be done with it. But you can also add other columns:

```
t.integer :contact_id
t.integer :campaign_id
t.date    :start_date
t.status  :string # 'active','stopped'
```

Now you can assign the attributes to the relationship:

```
campaign1 = Campaign.find(1)
campaign2 = Campaign.find(2)
contactA = Contact.find_by_name("A")
contactA.campaign_contacts.build(:status=>'active',
  :start_date => '2011-04-04',:campaign=>campaign1)
contactA.campaign_contacts.build(:status=>'stopped',
  :start_date => '2011-03-02',:campaign=>campaign1)
```

Comment: so I create a new migration for the database campaign_contacts?

Comment: would I do that with ruby script/generate migration add_columns_to_campaign_contacts ?

Comment: Like so: `script/generate model CampaignContact contact:references campaign:references`

Comment: @zetetic -- I see, so the table doesn't exist, I create it and then change everything that is has_many to a :through relationsihp?

Comment: @zetitic -- if I want to know the status of a campaign, I can use campaign.campaign_contacts.status?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that last comment. The `status` attribute belongs to the `CampaignContact` model, not the `Campaign` model. It would only make sense to call `:status` on the relationship (i.e. the row in the join table), not on the campaign itself.

Comment: so it would be campaigncontact.campaign_id_is(:campaign).status?

Comment: That would be one way to do it. You'd need to know both the campaign_d and the contact_id, of course, but the relationship could be accessed from either side.